# The need of an user model to use Rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auth0

I`m currently using Ruby on Rails API with Auth0 to create an API that I will consume with a React app.

The problem I have, is that Im unsure how to handle the storing of User information. Users are currently stored at Auth0 and Im using the Auth0 Authorization extension to handle groups, roles and permissions.

Here is where I get a little bit confused, I dont need an User model but it would be very handy to have one, so I could for example do User.find(user_id).teams, returning the list of teams that is associated with a user.

The problem with this is that I need to synchronized my user table with the user database over at Auth0.
So what should I do?

Should I use Auth0 for authentication and create a user in my database on login and have the user fill in the rest of his user profile.

I think I might have rubber ducked myself, but I would still like some input.

Should I use the knock gem or just use the Auth0 guide/tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Auth0, like the name suggests, can provide a simple login/logout system. Once your app exchanged with Auth0 and authenticated the end-user, you can simply grab the related user (based on the email for example) in your DB and start from there. Auth0 is just an external authentification service, once it confirmed the email/password combination you provided is valid, you can treat the end-user as authenticated and set the usual `current_user` helper

Comment: Okay, so I would simply use auth0 for authentication and create a corresponding user record for each user?

Comment: exactly, your app does not need to store the password (and should not). You will need a way to map the Auth0's response to a particular user though, maybe using the user's emaile for example.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! :)